# accept credit card on site using PayPal

Tags: php, paypal

Is it possible to accept credit card on site with PayPal ?. So when a user pay using his credit card the cash will be transfered to my paypal account. If it is possible, then which payment method I should use ? Express Checkout or something else ?

Thank you guys

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set up a business account with PayPal and read the documentation for their [Express Checkout integration](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECGettingStarted).

Under this method, the customer is redirected onto PayPal's site to perform the payment - either with an existing PayPal account, or using their credit/debit card if they don't already have one - and then redirected back to your site. You'll be able to use the PayPal API to ensure that the funds really have been transferred, and the money will appear in your PayPal account.

If you want the customer to remain on your site (i.e. enter their card details into your form), then you'll need to look into [Website Payments Pro](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_WPWebsitePaymentsPro), but bear in mind that handling the card data yourself obligates you to comply with the [PCI DSS](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/), which may be an extra burden you don't need.